# OpenGL: Draw line with point and directon vector

Tags: c++, opengl, line

I had seen OpenGL statement to draw a line using two points. However, my requirement is to draw a line using the following detail

- a point on a line
- Direction Vector

Im developing function in c++ using openGL library.

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And can you help me with the function if length is known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on the semantics of what you've termed a *direction vector*.

In the computer graphics context I would normally take that term to mean a *unit vector* facing in the specified direction.    Whereas in a mathematics context you *might* simply mean the *relative vector* that results from subtracting the two points' coordinates.

[Using P1 and P2 to represent the required two points, and V for the vector].

In the former case, you also need a specify a *length* for the vector, so you'll need:

```
P2 = P1 + n * V
```

whereas in the latter case, it's just trivially

```
P2 = P1 + V
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make that two-point line a very long one, say 10000 to each direction from your point-on-a-line:

```
void drawLinePointDirection(Point P, Vector D) {
    Point A = P + 10000*D;
    Point B = P - 10000*D
    drawLineTwoPoints(A, B);
}
```

assuming D is unit length.